# Passing array from PHP to JS iteratively

Tags: javascript, php, loops, variables

I'm passing variables from PHP to JS using the following approach:

```
var dbGen = parseInt("<?php echo $gen; ?>");
```

However, I'm struggling a lot to do this from an array (pushing each element from a PHP array to a JS array). This is because there I can't seem to place a JS iterator "i" inside the loop, as it recognizes it as php code:

```
var dbDNA = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dbDNA.push(parseInt("<?php echo $DNA[i]; ?>"));
}
```

I also tried writing a function (ES6) that would combine everything as a string and try to execute the php code, but that didn't work either:

```
function pushToArray(arr, ind){
    let str = `<?php echo ${arr}[${ind}]; ?>`;
    dbDNA.push(parseInt(str));
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pushToArray("$DNA", i);
}
```

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is sufficient...

```
var somevar = <?php echo json_encode( $array ); ?>;
```